# tramp + async-shell-command ignores shell-file-name

Tags: tramp, shell, async

If I locally call async-shell-command it takes the shell from shell-file-name (/bin/bash).

However if I use su or ssh via tramp to invoke a shell command remotely it always runs as /bin/sh.  The default shell on the remote box is bash.

This is not the case if run an interactive  M-x shell where the correct bash shell is always used, both remotely and locally.

My config looks like:

```
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "/bin/bash")
(setq shell-file-name explicit-shell-file-name)
```

I'm using emacs 25.3

Any ideas how to make bash the default shell when running shell commands via tramp?

Comment: the easiest way would have been logging into sh via tramp, then entering `bash <enter>` or running remote scripts with a shebang requiring bash at the top.  I know, not exactly automated/convenient, but fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tramp-handle-shell-command` carries the comment

```
;; We cannot use `shell-file-name' and `shell-command-switch',
;; they are variables of the local host.
```

Instead, it uses the arguments `tramp-remote-shell` and `tramp-remote-shell-args` from the variable `tramp-methods`. You can override them by tweaking `tramp-connection-properties`, the Tramp manual discusses exactly the given case in the section `Setting own connection related information`:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-connection-properties
             (list (regexp-quote "/ssh:user@randomhost.your.domain:")
                   "remote-shell" "/bin/ksh"))
(add-to-list 'tramp-connection-properties
             (list (regexp-quote "/ssh:user@randomhost.your.domain:")
                   "remote-shell-login" '("-")))
```